# Highcharts - Font Stretch

Tags: javascript, css, svg, highcharts

I would like to apply a `font-stretch` property to a text in Highcharts.
How can I do this ?

Here is a jsFiddle I've already tried : http://jsfiddle.net/5hPcP/11/

But it does nothing.

```
$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            events:{
                load: function(){
                       this.renderer.text('Stretched text',60, 60 ).
                            css({
                                fontStretch:"extra-expanded",
                                fontSize : "12pt"
                            }).attr({
                            fontStretch:"extra-expanded",
                            zIndex: 10000
                        }).add();
                }
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]
    });
});
```

[W3C CSS info](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-CSS2-20080411/fonts.html#propdef-font-stretch).

[W3C SVG text](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/text.html). Then search for `stretch`.

Comment: I guess you must use the proper SVG text attributes and not the CSS one. Maybe you want something like http://jsfiddle.net/5hPcP/12/

Comment: I have tried your jsFiddle but my text hasn't changed (Chrome 32, IE10)

Comment: Tested only on FF26. Sorry, can't help.

Comment: Ok I have some result on Firefox. But When I export to PDF, the stretching has disappeared. Thanks anyway. ;) I hope someone else can help me...

Comment: This should be possible to get when setting `useHTML` for `renderer.text`. However, I don't see any difference when setting this directly in styles (on mac). My test case: http://jsfiddle.net/5hPcP/16/

Comment: @PawełFus I don't see any difference too on IE, Chrome, Firefox. Thanks anyway for your help. ;)